# Powershell script to copy file to network runs manually, but not from Task Scheduler

Tags: powershell, networking, scheduled-tasks, copy-item

I am running a script to copy a file from a local to network location. The script works if I call it myself via powershell, but not from Task Scheduler. I have looked at [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/343496/powershell-script-works-from-command-line-not-from-task-scheduler-why) and many other articles, but I cannot get it to work. Right now I can look at the task scheduler, "Last run result" and it says the task is currently running for a couple minutes before I stop it. When I end the task I don't even get an exception (code is in a try/catch)

I have the ServerLocation and ServerFullPath broken up because I was trying a few different examples.

The code is as follows (with the domain/username/password substituted):

```
Set-Variable ServerCredentials -option Constant -value "<domain>/<username>  <password>"
Set-Variable ServerLocation -option Constant -value "\\<domain>"
Set-Variable ServerFullPath -option Constant -value $ServerLocation"\path\path"

$latest = Get-ChildItem -Path .\ | Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1
net use $ServerFullPath /user:$ServerCredentials

Copy-Item .\$latest $ServerFullPath -Force
```

I am new to powershell, any thoughts on how to troubleshoot? Need any more information?

Comment: Does your script work outside of task scheduler?

Comment: Yes, I can run just fine invoking the script from powershell. I put that in the title, but I can see that it was kind of obscure. Going to edit the text now.

Comment: Sorry I missed that, and are you using a .bat file to start the powershell in TaskScheduler?

Comment: I am not.
(Program/script): C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe

(Add Arguments): -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File NightlyBuildAndLoadTest.ps1

(Start in): C:\NightlyBuildScripts

Comment: you could try to start it from a bat file, that will atleast narrow down where the issue lies. you can also try to `bypass` instead of unrestricted for the execution policy

Comment: Ok, I will try those, thank you. I am pretty new however--how does starting from a .bat file change things?

Comment: It  just changes the way that it is called, for example I couldn't get it to work correctly by calling the script directly but if I use the bat files I get my powershells to run daily to take my inventory.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77851/discussion-between-jclark4321-and-luke).

Comment: Because the task is hanging, I am assuming that something is prompting. You can add `-NonInteractive` to your powershell.exe invocation (and in fact you should), but it won't help if it turns out that `net use` is the thing that is prompting. Consider converting that to [a call to `New-PSDrive` instead](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849829(v=wps.620).aspx).

Comment: How are you calling the script from Task Manager? Are you using the `-File` switch?

Comment: @Deadly-Bagel Yes, a reference to what I am using is about 6 comments up from here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this lies in how "net use" works. Typing "net use" into cmd showed I already had a connection, and it seems already having a connection will make net use want to prompt, which is why it seemed my script was hanging. I tried deleting the connection with "Net use * /delete /y", just above the original net use, and that allowed the script to continue correctly. It then looked like:

```
Net use * /delete /y
net use $ServerFullPath /user:$ServerCredentialUser $ServerCredentialPassword
```

The key here is the \y on the end, which will silently answer yes to the prompt.

As an aside [this link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490717.aspx) shows how to use the /delete param. I chose to use a * here, but it seems I could have deleted that specific connection.

However this sparked something that maybe net use was prompting me in some way about the connection that was already there, so I changed the original line to:

```
net use $ServerFullPath /user:$ServerCredentialUser $ServerCredentialPassword /y
```

With the /y on the end it works just fine, and all is well :)